# PHP shell_exec doesn't return anything when using sudo. Sudoers edited properly?

Tags: php, linux, shell, sudo

I have a page thats called form a browser which at the end needs to run one command as root. I am very well aware of the security implications of running shell_exec commands from the browser, so I have locked down my sudoers file for "apache all no password" to the one command:

```
apache  ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/rndc
```

I have made my PHP page hard-coded so no part of the command is run from user-accessible inputs.

This process just refreshes the config for Bind9 (named) by issuing

```
shell_exec("/usr/sbin/sudo /usr/sbin/rndc reload");
```

However, it seems this does not run, but when I have make /bin/bash the default shell for apache and as apache, this process runs when I try it in apache shell:

```
[root@localhost zones]# su - apache
-bash-4.2$ /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/rndc reload
server reload successful
```

My whole PHP code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
$result = shell_exec("/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/rndc reload");
print_r($result);
?>
```

I get no responses. Any ideas? SELinux is now set to permissive.

Answer (score 0):

turned out to be the require_ttl parameter in my sudo files. Apache was erring in /var/log/httpd/error_log.

Thats to those who viewed :)